# How to change css with javascript of multiple images - display: none to display: inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I would like the images to appear after I click the button.

HTML

```
<button class="knife-button" onclick="bayonetFunction()">Click to see more</button>

<div class="column1">
    <img src=""  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>

<div class="column1">
    <img src=""  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>
```

There s more images.

CSS

```
.bayonet {
      display: none;
 }
```

JS

```
function bayonetFunction(){
      document.getElementsByClassName('bayonet').style.display="inline";
}
```

This doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over all elements. See this code example:

```js
function bayonetFunction(){
  document.querySelectorAll('.bayonet').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = 'block';
  });
}
```

```css
.bayonet {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<button class="knife-button" onclick="bayonetFunction()">Click to see more</button>

<div class="column1">
    <img src=""  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>

<div class="column1">
    <img src=""  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function bayonetFunction(){
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bayonet'), function(d) {
  d.style.display ="inline";
});

}
```

```css
.bayonet {
      display: none;
 }
```

```html
<button class="knife-button" onclick="bayonetFunction()">Click to see more</button>

<div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ad45b8fc3a096c8d840bcedb819bfb8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>

<div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ad45b8fc3a096c8d840bcedb819bfb8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"  class="bayonet" alt="">
</div>
```